# How to always require email verification before accessing a page?

Tags: 7, security

I have a custom page defined by hook_menu.

I want signed in users to be required to verify their email every time they want to access it. The page will have buttons on it that would allow someone to export all the data related to the account.

I've looked around for existing modules that could provide this. This looked the most promising: [Email Required](https://www.drupal.org/project/email_required). However this only happens on their first visit to the page. So once the accounts email is verified the user would always have access to it.

How can I have people verify their email every time before allowing them to access the page? It would be good if the verification link in the email expired after a period of time if it isn't used for security.

Any pointers are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Because the page I was creating was actually a form, I found this module got me out of trouble [password_require](https://www.drupal.org/project/password_require)

Although strictly speaking my question didn't specify it was a form. Other than mentioning buttons.

Hope it helps someone